# Accessing the 1st and 2nd cylinder ignition coils in VW Golf MK5 (55 kw)

Tags: vw, golf, ignition-coil

I am replacing all of the ignition coils in my MK5 Golf as they keep they have all started to fail recently as per [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/75065/cylinder-misfires-since-having-a-full-service-on-golf-mk5-2005)

I have managed to change them with the exception of 1 and 2 because I am struggling to access them as they lie under the engine oil inlet. I could probably manage to get the 2nd one out with a bit of manipulation but I would rather do it properly.

Does anyone know how to do this correctly, I assume I need to remove the engine oil inlet?

**Images**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the white piece out by gently wiggling it. Should come out fairly easily (with some resistance). Then, grab the entire filler assembly and turn it counterclockwise. It has two tabs on it which locate it in the valve cover.

[image]

With the filler assembly removed, the coils should now be completely accessible.

You can always look at [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/I5cwpV8Oi-Y) on how to replace the spark plugs to get a visual of exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I have just changed all the ignition coils